# Deploying a mp3 asset on Flutter Web does not work on AWS amplify

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

for my flutter web project, I want to make a frontend to play mp3 music song using just audio.

[image: project structure]

This all works great locally, but when I build and deploy the web app on aws amplify, the audio player cannot find the mp3 file in the asset folder. This is strange, because every other artifact (Google Fonts, lottie animation json file) is found without problems. I always observe an 404 error in the browser console.

This is the player method... I´m trying to strip a bit from the path

```
  final player = AudioPlayer(); // Create a player

  Future playMp3(String mp3) async {
    mp3 = mp3.substring(7);
    print("Playing: $mp3");
    player.stop();
    final duration = await player
        .setUrl('asset:$mp3'); // Schemes: (https: | file: | asset: )
    player.play(); // Play without waiting for completion
  }
```

the print reports: "Playing: mp3/dilemmamusic.mp3" which is working locally fine.

The mp3 file is about 2MB of size (I already tried renaming the extension but no difference on aws - while local test works) in the case that aws blocks mp3 files being deployed...but no success

Any ideas why this does not work on aws?
Thanks!